# Rails : search multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've managed to build a simple search model and have four attributes that can be searched; name, age, location and gender. The problem I am having is I can't seem to find the right code to search multiple attributes.

For example a search for "adam" should produce all users named adam, whereas a search for london should display all users from london. I can only search one attribute individually (name) so if I type in "london" it displays a blank result page.

**/people/index.html.erb** (search form)

```
<%= form_tag people_path, :method => 'get'  do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
  <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

**models/person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :age, :gender, :location, :name
  def self.search(search, id)
    if search
      where(['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"]) 
    else  
      scoped
    end
  end
end
```

**people_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @people = Person.search(params[:search], params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Modify your `search` method so that it accepts a hash of fields to search by. Writing this for you is outside the scope of Stack Overflow. Please at least *try* to implement it yourself and post your progress if you get stuck.

Comment: I have tried many different ways to implement this function including seven or eight different tutorials for writing search functions and each time it throws an error or doesn't crash but doesn't display the correct results either. I have tried quite a few different ways of adding multiple search fields but can not find the correct syntax.. hence why I posted here because I am truly stuck.

Answer (score 1):

The following code worked fine.

```
where('name LIKE ? OR location LIKE ?', "%#{search}%","%#{search}%")
```

@meagar, I fail to understand how that simple line of code "is outside the scope of Stack Overflow".

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [Sunspot_rails](http://sunspot.github.io/) gem for your problem, it integrate [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) search engine platform into Rails and is a battle proved solution for Rails app. In my company's website [Fishtrip.cn](http://www.fishtrip.cn) we use solr to search for both House, Transportation retailer and tours. It might be a little bit heavy for your project, but if are looking for a powerful solution then Sunspot definitely would be one of it.